# Java assigning values to arrays / objects

Tags: java, arrays, object

I am converting to Java from Javascript (cause of university) and cannot seem to come around to the logic of array / object assignment. 
What I'm trying to achieve is to have something like used to be in Pascal "record" with different variables. This then call in main class and create few instances of that. This is the simple structure I have for example:

```
class shoppingCart {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        // Define objects
        Product[] products = new Product[3];        

        // Fill in products
        products[0] = {
            title: "Product 1",
            code: "AB432",
            price: 13.60,
            quantity: "dozen"
        }                    
    }
}

class Product {
    public String title;
    public String code;
    public float price;
    public String quantity;
}
```

Can someone please point me the right way how to create "records" and how to assign values to them? I had the same problem with array in Java before when I declared the variable (array) and later tried

```
someArray = {23,2,32,523}
```

and compiler gives me error...

Comment: You would learn a lot by trying to provide a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) expample.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create an object... ideally *without* using public fields. For example, if you give your `Product` class a constructor taking the four values, you can use:

```
Product[] products = 
{
    new Product("Product 1", "AB432", 13.6, "dozen"),
    new Procuct( /* etc */ )
};
```

Also note that you shouldn't use `float` to store a price. Use `BigDecimal` instead, or an integer number of cents/pennies/whatever.

Comment: Tank you for the answer, didn't think about doing it that way. Nice and clean. But seriously dont understand why the question has 2 down-votes...

Comment: @Tom: While neither of the downvotes was mine, "and compiler gives me error" is never a good sign. Any time you've got an error message, you should include it in the question.

Answer (score 1):

**First add a constructor to your product class.**

```
class Product {
    public String title;
    public String code;
    public float price;
    public String quantity;

   public Product(String title, String code, float price, String quantity){
      this.title = title;
      this.code = code;
      this.price = price;
      this.quantity = quantity;
   }
}
```

**Then add instances of product to your array**

```
class shoppingCart {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        // Define objects
        Product[] products = new Product[3];        

        // Fill in products
        products[0] = new Product("Product 1", "AB432", 13.60, "dozen");
        //repeat for other products.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The convention is Java is what are called Beans (en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaBeans), that have private member variables and getter and setter methods. You would initialize it something like...

```
Product product = new Product();
product.setTitle("Product 1");
product.setCode("AB432");
product.setPrice(13.60);
product.setQuantity("dozen");
products[0] = product;
```

Also, you can only initialise an array like that when you first declare it...

```
int[] someArray = {23,2,32,523};
```